# A file uploaded with HTTP PUT has extra data at the beginning and the end

Tags: c#, .net, iis, upload

I need to implement uploading and downloading files as cheap as possible. For my tests I use Windows XP with IIS 5 and a console C# program.

I created a virtual directory in IIS and in my program I execute the following code:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webClient.UploadFile( "http://localhost/Exchange/file.jpg", "PUT", localPathToMyFile );
```

those lines execute successfully and a file appears in the directory used to serve contents to the virtual directory. The problem is the file contents in surrounded by extra data:

```
-----------------------8ccfabf2a995855
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
//file contents goes here
-----------------------8ccfabf2a995855
```

Where does this extra data come from? What do I do so that it doesn't appear, but the file is uploaded as is?

Comment: Can you post the server-side code that's handling the upload?

Comment: @John Sheehan: There's no code. I wanted to go cheap and hoped the server would have some default magic for that.

Comment: +1 For an example of showing a WebClient PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra data comes from the HTTP protocol, see [here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/001003.htm). Try changing the method to "POST" and create aa simple ASP.net webpage that receives and saves the file. Like the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's how HTML forms are uploaded.

Explanation:
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/001003.htm

Actual specification
http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html

How do you save the files?